# SQL select rows that have one value but not another

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL which will contain multiple rows for one id, as below

```
accountid   Productname
1           GL
1           IP
1           MI
2           GL
2           IP
2           PA
3           MI
3           CP
3           IP
4           GL
4           CP
4           CI
```

I want to be able to select all accounts which have certain products but not other. For example all that have IP or GL but not MI, using the sample table above this would return accounts 2 and 4.

```
SELECT ccx_accountidname
FROM (
    SELECT ccx_accountidname, ccx_productname
    FROM Filteredccx_leadresearch
    WHERE ccx_productname IN ('GL','IP')
    AND ccx_accountidname IS NOT NULL
    ) AS T
WHERE ccx_productname NOT IN ('MI')
ORDER BY ccx_accountidname
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT LR1.ccx_accountidname
FROM Filteredccx_leadresearch LR1
LEFT JOIN Filteredccx_leadresearch LR2 ON LR1.ccx_accountid =   LR2.ccx_accountid 
AND LR2.ccx_productname IN ('GL', 'IP')
WHERE LR1.ccx_productname NOT IN ('MI')
AND LR1.ccx_accountidname IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY LR1.ccx_accountidname
```

Both give basically the same results, is there any way this can be done?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: are these the ONLY two columns?

Comment: No there are a lot of columns but these are the only 2 that really concern me at the moment

Comment: More columns gives you the chance to pivot, but it depends on the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.Accountidname FROM TheTableThatContainsAccountnames as T1
JOIN AccountProductsTable as T2 on T1.AccountId=T2.AccountId
WHERE T2.ProductName = 'ProductYouWant'
AND T2.ProductName = 'AnOtherProductYouWant'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul. Unfortunately this still won't work, I can't use AND on the where clause as the product field will only contain one product. I tried OR but it still pulls through accounts that have other products.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood the problem. I'm currently looking for a solution, but it is not as trivial as I thought...

Answer (score 0):

According to your post, all you really need is a simple query with the correct and logic. You want all accounts with Product name GL or IP but not in MI. This will do it without any other joins.

```
  SELECT ccx_accountidname
  FROM Filteredccx_leadresearch
  WHERE 
       ccx_productname in ('GL','IP')
       and ccx_productname not in ('MI')
```

**EDIT**

This will get you the account, though I doubt it will work in your overall solution. It's just hard to tell without seeing your complete dataset. This could be done with parameters too.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempTable

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTableTwo') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempTableTwo

create table #TempTable (accountid int, productname char(2))
insert into #TempTable (accountid,productname) values
(1,'GL'),
(1,'IP'),
(1,'MI'),
(2,'GL'),
(2,'IP'),
(2,'MA')


select distinct
    t1.accountid, 
    1 as T
into #TempTableTwo
from 
    #TempTable t1
where
    productname in ('GL','IP')
union all
select distinct
    t1.accountid, 
    -1 as T
from 
    #TempTable t1
where
     productname in ('MI')

select
    accountid
from #TempTableTwo
group by accountid
having sum(T) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think it's that simple. Using this method would still return the accounts that have MI if they also have IP or GL. Thanks

Comment: This returns the accounts that do NOT have MI, hence the `NOT IN`. Perhaps I'm confused as to your true expected output or there is something missing in your code that you need returned or taken into consideration.

Comment: I've probably not explained things properly. In my sample table accountid 1 has rows for GL, IP and MI. As it has MI I wouldn't want this account to appear at all but in this query it would because it also has GL and IP. Accountid 2 has GL, IP and PA so I would want to show as it doesn't have MI. Does this make any sense at all?

Comment: Ah ok, that's better. That clears it up for us a lot

Comment: ok added something for you, but it's only idealistic with the minimal dataset given. Hopefully it spawns ideas though

Comment: That's amazing thank you, i'll have a play around with it in work tomorrow. I had been thinking about creating a temp table with the values in so thanks for the input. It's a table from our CRM system so there's probably somewhere around 50 columns in it!

Comment: No worries. If you have any questions related to this post keep them coming. If it's unrelated, open another question for everyone to chime in on. And of course, if any solution works for you accept it as the answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late for the game, but this should do the trick, if anyone is trying to solve a similar problem. I renamed your table and it's columns:

```
Filteredccx_leadresearch -> l_search
ccx_accountidname -> a_name
ccx_productname -> p_name
```

And here's the SQL:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT t1.a_name
   FROM l_search t1
   JOIN l_search t2 ON t1.a_name = t2.a_name
   WHERE t1.p_name = 'IP'
     OR t2.p_name = 'GL') 

MINUS

(SELECT DISTINCT t1.a_name
   FROM l_search t1
   JOIN l_search t2 ON t1.a_name = t2.a_name
   WHERE ((t1.p_name = 'IP'OR t1.p_name = 'GL') AND t2.p_name = 'MI')
     OR 
         (t1.p_name = 'MI' AND (t1.p_name = 'IP' OR t1.p_name = 'GL')));
```

**First set:**
cross product of table on itself with same IDs, get account IDs which have a product 'IP' or 'GL'.

**Second set:**
cross product of table on itself with same IDs, get account IDs which have p_name ('IP' OR 'GL') on first cross property AND 'MI' on second.
Also, get those IDs, which have the same but the other way around: p_name 'MI' on first cross property AND ('IP' OR 'GL') on second.

And finally subtract the **second** from the **first**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to include the accounts that match either IP or GL and exclude those accounts if they have an record for MI without using a subquery.

This is assuming t1 is a table that has unique account numbers in accountid and t2 is the table you have shown above that has accountid and Productname columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.accountid
FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 AS t2_match
        ON t1.accountid = t2_match.accountid
        AND
        (
            t2_match.Productname = 'IP'
            OR t2_match.Productname = 'GL'
        )
    LEFT JOIN t2 AS t2_not_match
        ON t1.accountid = t2_not_match.accountid
        AND t2_not_match.Productname = 'MI'
WHERE
    t2_match.accountid IS NOT NULL
    AND t2_not_match.accountid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really late, but it might help some one.

I'll focus only on using the columns we have on the table we are shown (won't combine it with other tables we were not given).

Since the only table in the example is not clearly named, I'll call it `some_table`

---

```
SELECT t.accountidname, t.productname
FROM some_table t
WHERE t.productname IN ('GL','IP')
AND t.accountidname NOT IN (
    SELECT accountidname
    FROM some_table
    WHERE productname = 'MI'
);
```

The idea here is to:

1. Select all **accountid** and **productname** that have **productname** either `GL` or `IP` (3rd line)
2. Select all **accountid** that have a **productname** `MI` and remove them from the values we already have (4th line onwards)

---

With this values, filtering or combining it with other tables should be rather trivial.

You might want to replace the `SELECT` with `SELECT DISTINCT` if the combinations of **accountid** and **productname** could be repeated in the table.